# Unable to locate xpath for an element "::after"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the below code:

```
<em class="x-btn-split" unselectable="on" id="ext-gen67"><button type="button" id="ext-gen33" class=" x-btn-text"><div class="mruIcon"></div><span>Cases</span></button>::after</em>
```

I need to get the xpath of ::after, I am unable to get the xpath. I have attached the image.

[image: xpath]

Comment: What are you going to do with it then?

Comment: i don't think selenium support's it. https://thenewcircle.com/static/bookshelf/selenium_tutorial/locators.html#_css

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try out:

```
//em/button/following-sibling::text()
```